# InnerException {"Invalid object name 'dbo.Users'"}

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am currently trying to setup an ASP.Net MVC 3 Application for the first time. I know what I am doing with Ruby on Rails but completely lost with ASP.Net.  I would like the app to create the database but not sure what I am doing wrong. I have an empty Database build called ssDB. I have setup the connectionStrings and built out the Model classes. According to everything I have read thus for, when I go to the run the App it should create the database but it doesn't look that way.

The Abbreviated Error I get is:

```
InnerException: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
Message=Invalid object name 'dbo.Users'.
Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
ErrorCode=-2146232060
Class=16
LineNumber=1
Number=208
Procedure=""
Server=TESTSVR01
State=1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have an empty Database build called ssDB

You have created an empty database with no tables. Since there is a database EF assumes tables are also created. Hence it will not proceed to create the tables.

You can drop the database and allow EF to create the database and the tables.

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced the same issue while using Database first approach. Connection string in my service's/service's host web.config was incorrect. I corrected the connection string and it worked.